# Having problem while loading data from server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Access to fetch at 'https://nameless-mesa-03450.herokuapp.com/item' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code, it is a shot in the dark for us to answer this question. However, this is a common error. In your server side code, import the npm package cors then use it by passing it into the `app.use` method of express.

```
const cors = require('cors')
 
app.use(cors())
```

This will work if you are using express on the backend